# Jquery Alphabetically not sort on Repeater control by asc and desc

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a Repeater control that has some classes inside but I have to sort the list alphabetically, both ascending and descending. It is not working perfectly. Kindly help me figure out the problems. I have used two buttons for asc and desc which shown outside the repeater control. Can anyone solve my problems.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $('.link-sort-list').click(function (e) {
                debugger;
                var $sort = this;
                var $list = $('.fleftFiveDivs');
                var $listLi = $('.box', $list);
                //var $listLi = $("input [id*=RepDetails]",$list);
                $listLi.sort(function (a, b) {
                    var keyA = $(a).text();
                    var keyB = $(b).text();
                    if ($($sort).hasClass('asc')) {
                        return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
                    } else {
                        return (keyA < keyB) ? 1 : 0;
                    }
                });
                $.each($listLi, function (index, row) {
                    $list.append(row);
                });

                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
 <div class="fleftFiveDivs" id="style-4">

 <asp:Repeater ID="RepDetails" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="box">
             <div class="lblposise">
                 <img class="group list-group-image" src="../Images/un.png" style="width: 40px; margin-top: -34px;" alt="" />
             </div>
             <div class="lblposise">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblvesselname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("vesselname") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
             </div>
             <div class="lblposise">
                 <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
             </div>
             <div class="lblposise">
                 <asp:Label ID="lblvesselid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("vesselid") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
             </div>
             <div class="lblposise">
                <%--  <asp:Label ID="lblstartdate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SubscriptionActivationDate","{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' Font-Bold="true" />--%>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SubscriptionActivationDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>
             </div>
             <div class="lblposise">
                 <%-- <asp:Label ID="lblenddate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TokenSubscriptionDate","{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' Font-Bold="true" />--%>
                 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TokenSubscriptionDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>
             </div>
             <div class="lblposise">
                 <asp:Label ID="lblnousers" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Users") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
             </div>
             <div class="lblposise">
                 75 %
             </div>
             <div class="lblposise">
                 75 %
             </div>
             <div class="lblposise">
                 Done
             </div>
             <div class="lblposise">
                 Done
             </div>
             <div class="lblposise">
                 Done
             </div>
             <div class="lblbtnposi">
                 <input type="submit" value="View Details" class="btn" />
             </div>
         </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Looks like your $List and $ListLi might be to greedy. If you are using a repeater my guess is you are probably going to have multiple i.e. $(".box").length > 1 I would be curious what that count is.

Comment: how can implement this.

Comment: Cleaned up the text (made sentences starting with a capital letter and ending with a .). Removed useless whitespace from code

Comment: "It is not working perfectly" - what *does* work? What do you see happening and what did you expect? Please [edit] that into your question

Comment: My suggestion to you is to get this working without asp.net. Get the jquery working with just the html in a jsfiddle or locally. Then implement the asp.net. It sounds like you are not really sure what questions to ask. So start with the smallest parts and understand how they work. Then bring in everything else.

Comment: Thanks sir for your valuable suggestion